# Display video thumbnails from directory

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display video thumbnails, with the videos located in a directory, and with  all different kinds of formats.  I followed this tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/display-video-thumbnail-in-listview.html .  It works good, but I am looking to display files that I am don't know the exact name/path to.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) and then add the result bitmap into your widget.

Comment: I have that from the tutorial, and it works if I point it to the exact file.  I want to display the thumbnails that are located in a given directory.

Comment: Right, then you should read this tutorial, http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: In your case you should use BitmapFactory.decodeFile instead of BitmapFactory.decodeResource